How to import Python module into a Python script in Glue AWS
I have a project with this structure:
└── external_variables
    ├── anatel_access_data linux.py
    ├── anatel_access_data.py
    ├── bsria_variables.py
    ├── future_external_variables.py
    ├── past_external_variables.py
    └── utils
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── helper.py
        ├── redshift.py
        └── scriptcase.py

In my bsria_variables.py I have the following imports:
from utils.redshift import connect_redshift, save_to_redshift
from utils.scriptcase import connect_sc, read_from_script_case

I uploaded the bsria_variables.py into a Python Script in Glue
I zipped the content of utils folder into utils.zip and uploaded into an s3 bucket
However, when I run the script it throws me an error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
So, How can I import extra Python files into a script?
Obs: In my machine works. Also, I provided an IAM Role that has access to S3 to be able to see those files.
I added screenshots to complete the question:
Error on running

bsria_variables.py:

I informed the utils.zip in both Python library path and Referenced files path:


I was able to overcome this error with the following import:
from external_variables.utils import scriptcase, redshift

I only inform the path of my .whl file into Python library path, which in this case it was s3://aws-glue-assets-515113300956-us-east-1/libraries/external_variables/external_variables-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
The most important thing to overcome this solution was to figure out that I had a Python shell job. And it does not accept .zip files
